# Working with Lift-JSON in Scala convert map to string

Tags: json, scala, lift, lift-json

i am working on Scala -  i used JacksMapper it works fine, 
here goes the code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.ObjectInputStream
import scala.util.Marshal
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.PrintWriter
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSONArray
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference
import scala.collection.mutable._
//import com.lambdaworks.jacks.JacksMapper
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.FileReader
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.JsonDSL._

import net.liftweb.json.JsonAST._
import net.liftweb.json.Extraction._
import net.liftweb.json.Printer._

//import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._

object jsonTest extends Serializable{

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var i = 1
    val map = new HashMap[String, Any]() with scala.collection.mutable.SynchronizedMap[String, Any]

    while(i < 10000)
    {

    var in_list = List[Any]()
    in_list :+= "dummy"
    in_list :+= "dummy"
    in_list :+= "dummy"

    val in_map = HashMap[String,Any]()
    in_map("dummy"+i) = in_list

    var out_list = List[Any]()
    out_list :+= "cat1" 
    out_list :+= "hash1"
    out_list :+= 100
    out_list :+= (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000).toInt
    out_list :+= in_map

    map("dummy"+i) = out_list
    i = i + 1
    }

    val json = JacksMapper.writeValueAsString[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]](map.toMap)



    Some(new PrintWriter("foo.txt")).foreach{p => p.write(json); p.close}
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val br : BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.txt"));
    val sb:StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      var line = br.readLine();

       while (line != null) {
           sb.append    (line);
           sb.append("\n");
           line = br.readLine();
       }
       val content = sb.toString();
       br.close()

       println(content.length())

    val obj = JacksMapper.readValue[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]](content)
       val obj = scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]
    println(obj("dummy3"))
    println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t1)


  }

  }
```

But i am trying to use Lift_Json for scala.
please give me some idea how to change the above code with Lift_Json tags
i got Jar file of Lift_Json and worked on simple parse like compact(render(json)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should accomplish what you are looking to do. It will generate your test `Map` and then serialize that to a `JSON` String and write it out to a file. The next step will read it back in and extract it to a Map which you can read from - as in your above example.

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import java.io._

implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats

val map = {
  val mb = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Any]()
  (1 to 10000).foreach { i =>
    val in_list = "dummy" :: "dummy" :: "dummy" :: Nil
    val in_map = Map("dummy%s".format(i) -> in_list)
    mb += "dummy%s".format(i) -> List("cat1", "hash1", 100, (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000).toInt, in_map) 
  }
  mb.toMap
}

val json = Extraction.decompose(map)

val jsonStrOut = Printer.pretty(JsonAST.render(json))
val fileName = "foo.txt"

val fw = new FileWriter(fileName)
fw.write(jsonStrOut)
fw.close()

val jsonStrIn = scala.io.Source.fromFile(fileName).mkString

val obj = parse(jsonStrIn).asInstanceOf[JObject].values
println(obj("dummy3"))
```

While this is doable, I would highly recommend taking advantage of `case classes` and other Scala constructs to help with the serialization and de-serialization. Lift is really good at working with those object. Unless there is a reason for having everything untyped in a big Map, I think you'll save yourself a lot of headaches in the long run.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/paranamer/ParameterNamesNotFoundException
 at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.decompose(Extraction.scala:81)
 at JsonLift$.main(JsonLift.scala:20)
 at JsonLift.main(JsonLift.scala)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.paranamer.ParameterNamesNotFoundException
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 ... 3 more

Comment: Seems, like you are missing the `paranamer` jar from your classpath. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/liftweb/dpJE5g7cuF8/XCQzEJcOkYoJ